# Are child components of a memoized component memoized too?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization, react-usememo

Does the child component returned from useMemo or wrapped in React.memo() are memoized too?
(Apologies, this might be a silly question)

For example:

```
React.memo(<Parent><Child/></Parent>);
```

Here the Parent is memoized, is the Child too memoized?

Comment: Note that the example here isn't even valid, you don't `memo()` a JSX element, you `memo()` the component function or class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child isn't memoized in the sense that React doesn't apply `React.memo` to the child too.

But the child is memoized in the following sense:
Let's say component A is wrapped in `React.memo` and its child component B not. If A is not re rendered because of memoization then B will not re render too.

Also from the docs:

> React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component
> wrapped in React.memo has a useState or useContext Hook in its
> implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

So if components state gets modified, then it will be re rendered, despite if it or parent is memoized.

Also if A is re rendered because something in its **state** changed, then its child B will re render too (assuming B is not memoized).