# Rendering taking too much time in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

I am iterating over just 100 documents on a page and am using a wrapper component for some conditional things.

```
  const onClickCheckbox = (order: OrderProps) => {
    const _ordersToExport = [...ordersToExport];
    const index = _ordersToExport.map(({ order }) => order.id).indexOf(order.order.id);
    if (index === -1) {
      _ordersToExport.push(order);
    } else {
      _ordersToExport.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setOrdersToExport(_ordersToExport);
  };

return (
  <>
    {orders.map(({ order, ...rest }, index) => {
      return (
        <div className="booking-details" key={order.id}>
          <Grid container className="bg-dark" mt={2} alignItems="center">
            <Grid md={6} className="text-left" item>
              <Checkbox id="id1" checked={ordersToExport?.map(({ order }) => order.id).includes(order.id)} className="white" onChange={() => onClickCheckbox({ order, ...rest })} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid md={6} className="text-right" item>
              <ButtonGroup variant="text" aria-label="button group" className="white-btn-group">
                  <>
                    <ActionsAccess btnType="Accept" status={order.status}>
                      <Tooltip title="Accept" placement="top" arrow>
                        <Button size="large" onClick={() => updateOrder(order, 2)}>
                          <CheckIcon />
                        </Button>
                      </Tooltip>
                    </ActionsAccess>
                    <ActionsAccess btnType={"Accept and open document"} status={order.status}>
                      <Tooltip title="Accept and open document" placement="top" arrow>
                        <Button size="large" onClick={() => onClickAcceptOpen(order, 2)}>
                          <TaskIcon />
                        </Button>
                      </Tooltip>
                    </ActionsAccess>
                    <ActionsAccess btnType={"Accept and add note"} status={order.status}>
                      <Tooltip title="Accept and add note" placement="top" arrow>
                        <Button size="large" onClick={() => handleChange(`panel${`${index}-note`}`)}>
                          <SmsIcon />
                        </Button>
                      </Tooltip>
                    </ActionsAccess>
                    <ActionsAccess btnType={"B-Scan"} status={order.status}>
                      <Tooltip title="B-Scan" placement="top" arrow>
                        <Button size="large" onClick={() => handleChange(`panel${`${index}-bscan`}`)}>
                          <SystemUpdateAlt />
                        </Button>
                      </Tooltip>
                    </ActionsAccess>
                  </>
                <ActionsAccess btnType={"View document"} status={order.status}>
                  <Tooltip title="View document" placement="top" arrow>
                    <Button size="large" onClick={() => window.open(`/mybooking/overview-today/view-pdf?id=${order.id}`)}>
                      <DescriptionIcon />
                    </Button>
                  </Tooltip>
                </ActionsAccess>
                <ActionsAccess btnType={"Delete order"} status={order.status}>
                  <Tooltip title="Delete order" placement="top" arrow onClick={() => handleChange(`panel${`${index}-delete`}`)}>
                    <Button size="large">
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </Button>
                  </Tooltip>
                </ActionsAccess>
                  <ActionsAccess btnType={"Reject order"} status={order.status}>
                    <Tooltip title="Reject order" placement="top" arrow onClick={() => handleChange(`panel${`${index}-reason`}`)}>
                      <Button size="large">
                        <CancelIcon />
                      </Button>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </ActionsAccess>
                <ActionsAccess btnType={"View tracking"} status={order.status}>
                  <Tooltip title="View tracking" placement="top" arrow>
                    <Button
                      size="large"
                      onClick={() => {
                        navigate(`/event-tracking?id=${order.id}`);
                        setCount(count + 1);
                      }}
                    >
                      <ZoomInIcon />
                    </Button>
                  </Tooltip>
                </ActionsAccess>
                <ActionsAccess btnType="Quick edit" status={order.status}>
                  <Tooltip title="Quick edit" placement="top" arrow>
                    <Button size="large" onClick={() => onClickQuickEdit({ order, ...rest })}>
                      <FlashOnIcon />
                    </Button>
                  </Tooltip>
                </ActionsAccess>
                  <ActionsAccess btnType={"Modify order"} status={order.status}>
                    <Tooltip title="Modify order" placement="top" arrow>
                      <Button size="large" onClick={() => navigate(`/edit-order?id=${order.id}`)}>
                        <EditIcon />
                      </Button>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </ActionsAccess>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

Now I am not able to understand why it is taking too much time to check the checkBox on that I click.

Shouldn't I use wrapper component here? And go with the just conditional rendering inside the component (which looks code ugly unreadable)?

Here is my ActionAccess component.

```
const enums: Enums = {
  1: [
    "Accept",
    "Accept and open document",
    "Accept and add note",
    "View document",
    "Delete order",
    "Reject order",
    "View tracking",
    "Modify order",
  ],
  2: ["View document", "Delete order", "Reject order", "View tracking"],
  3: ["View document", "Delete order", "View tracking"],
  4: ["View document", "Delete order", "View tracking", "Modify order", "Quick edit"],
  8: ["View document", "Delete order", "View tracking", "Modify order", "Quick edit"],
  5: ["View document", "View tracking"],
  9: ["View document", "Delete order", "View tracking", "Modify order"]
};

export default function ActionsAccess({ children, status, btnType }: props) {
  const feature = enums[status];
  return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;
}
```

I have also tried:

I used useMemo with the Action access. Something like this:

```
export default function ActionsAccess({ children, status, btnType }: props) {
  const memoChildren = React.useMemo(() => {
    const feature = enums[status];
    return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;
  }, [status]);
  return memoChildren;
}
```

Still it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the limitation of [`React.memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo), consider [Bhavya Dhiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167172/bhavya-dhiman)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341090/rendering-taking-too-much-time-in-reactjs#comment136346798_77341090) of assigning a `key` prop to each `ActionsAccess` component and looping through them using an array.

That can help React identify which components have changed, been added, or removed, which helps to get more efficient updates.

Make sure every `ActionsAccess` component has a unique `key` prop.

```js
<ActionsAccess key={btnType} btnType={btnType} status={order.status}>
  {/* */}
</ActionsAccess>
```

And create an array of button types and loop through it to render your `ActionsAccess` components.
This follows "[Rendering Lists](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists)", using a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const buttonTypes = [
  "Accept",
  "Accept and open document",
  "Accept and add note",
  // other button types
];

return buttonTypes.map(btnType => (
  <ActionsAccess key={btnType} btnType={btnType} status={order.status}>
    {/* */}
  </ActionsAccess>
));
```

You would get:

```js
return (
  <>
    {orders.map(({ order, ...rest }, index) => {
      const buttonTypes = enums[order.status];
      return (
        <div className="booking-details" key={order.id}>
          <Grid container className="bg-dark" mt={2} alignItems="center">
            {/* rest of your component */}
            <Grid md={6} className="text-right" item>
              <ButtonGroup variant="text" aria-label="button group" className="white-btn-group">
                {buttonTypes.map(btnType => (
                  <ActionsAccess key={btnType} btnType={btnType} status={order.status}>
                    {/* render button based on btnType */}
                  </ActionsAccess>
                ))}
              </ButtonGroup>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

---

> Can't I use `React.memo` with `const feature = enums[status];   return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;`?

`React.memo` is a higher order component that memorizes the rendered output of the wrapped component and re-uses it unless the props to the component change.
However, as mentioned before, `React.memo` only performs a shallow comparison of the previous and new props, which means it compares primitive values directly and only compares the references of object values.

In the code `const feature = enums[status]; return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;` within the `ActionsAccess` component, `React.memo` can be used, but it would only be effective if the props (`status`, `btnType`, and `children`) to `ActionsAccess` change infrequently or have stable references.

If `status` and `btnType` are primitive values and change infrequently, `React.memo` should help prevent unnecessary renders of `ActionsAccess`. However, if `children` is a new array or object on each render, `React.memo`'s shallow comparison will not prevent re-renders, because the reference to `children` would be different each time.

```js
const ActionsAccess = React.memo(function ActionsAccess({ children, status, btnType }) {
  const feature = enums[status];
  return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;
});
```

For `React.memo` to be effective in this scenario, you would need to make sure the `children` prop has a stable reference. One way to achieve that might be to use [`React.useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) to [memoize](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/memoization-in-javascript-and-react/) the `children` prop in the parent component. After reading "[Are child components of a memoized component memoized too?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289597/6309)":

```js
const memoizedChildren = useMemo(() => {
  // compute children
  return children;
}, [/* dependencies */]);

<ActionsAccess children={memoizedChildren} status={status} btnType={btnType} />
```

That way, the reference to `children` remains stable across renders, unless the dependencies change.

But: the effectiveness of `memoizedChildren` would depend on what is causing the re-renders in the first place:

- If the `ActionsAccess` component's rendering is primarily affected by prop changes, then using `React.memo` with `memoizedChildren` might help in preventing unnecessary re-renders.
- If the re-rendering is being triggered by state or context changes within `ActionsAccess` or its children, then `React.memo` and `memoizedChildren` will not prevent those re-render.

---

> I think this is something related to MUI button (or components) they takes too much time to re render.
> Well I could not find any reason why so, but as of now `React.useMemo` works with the `ActionAccess` component
>
> ```js
> const memoChildren = React.useMemo(() => {
>  const feature = enums[status];
>  return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;
> }, [status, btnType]);
> ```
>
> Could help me why MUI button (or components) that much of time to re render?"

True, in terms of the `React.useMemo` optimization in the `ActionsAccess` component, the updated memoization dependency array to include both `status` and `btnType` would make sure the memoized value is recomputed only when either `status` or `btnType` change, which should help in reducing the number of re-renders, provided that the values of `status` and `btnType` change infrequently.

Try and avoid using inline functions or creating new objects/arrays as props, as these will cause components to re-render since new references are created on every render.

```js
// Instead of this:
<Button onClick={() => handleOnClick()} />

// Do this:
<Button onClick={handleOnClick} />
```

Utilize the [React DevTools Profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html) to identify components that are re-rendering frequently or taking a long time to render, and focus on optimizing these components.

And, if possible, consider lazy loading or asynchronously loading parts of the component tree that are not immediately needed.
If the MUI components are proving to be too heavy for your use case, consider creating custom, lightweight components that only include the necessary styling and behavior for your application.

Comment: Thanks.. I did use it but still it is lagging... Can't i use React.memo with `const feature = enums[status];
  return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;
`?

Comment: @Profer I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: So do I need use useEffect for every children? How can I include it in my loop ?

Comment: @Profer Using [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) can help control side effects in response to prop or state changes, but it doesn't inherently prevent re-renders.

Comment: Sorry I meant useMemo not useEffect. But still what you have given did not work. I have updated the question as well. And I am sure the above code is what causing the issue

Comment: @Profer But useMemo might also perform shallow comparisons. If children contains new objects or arrays on every render, the memoization will not prevent re-renders because the references are different.

Comment: I think this is something related to MUI button (or components) they takes too much time to re render. Well I could not find any reason why so but as of now React.useMemo works with the ActionAccess component. `const memoChildren = React.useMemo(() => {
    const feature = enums[status];
    return feature?.indexOf(btnType) !== -1 ? children : null;
  }, [status,btnType]);`

Comment: Thanks for the help but if you could help me why MUI button (or components) that much of time to re render?

Comment: @Profer I have edited the answer to address your comment, adding some suggestions for you to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Use PureComponent or React.memo: If your component doesn't rely on external props or state, you can use React.PureComponent or React.memo to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

```
import React from 'react';

const YourFunctionalComponent = React.memo(function YourComponent(props) 
{
  // ...
});
```

something like this

Comment: The problem is React.memo do a shallow comparison and does not work for the deep object and it considers children to be a new array always

Answer (score 0):

100(s) of items really shouldn't require a virtual each or [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Maybe try optimizing the checkbox state before getting into those strategies.

```
checked={ordersToExport?.map(({ order }) => order.id).includes(order.id)}
```

will do that iteration on every item, on every click, and on every render.

It could just be adding up. Try using a property in your order item, like ...{export: true/false}, and then checked just becomes part of the parent iteration:

```
checked={order?.export}
```